# How to index and match the second matching value

Tags: excel, vba

When I use the VBA Excel functions INDEX and MATCH, it indexes the first value that matches the values, but I want to use it to also find the second value that matches the criteria. How can I do that?

Attached below is what I have, but it only works for the first indexed value.

```
IFERROR(INDEX('Page2'!$A$1:$" & Split(Worksheets("Page2").UsedRange.Address, "$")(3) & "$" & lastrowvalue & ",MATCH($J575,'DATA Page2'!$A:$A,0), MATCH(U$1,'Page2'!$1:$1,0) ), 0)"
```

Comment: Hi, had same thing to do, I've solved it by going through big->smaller->small range with .find // .find.next function just for each time setting new (smaller) range for .find and storing them in different dims.

Answer (score -1):

Change the last value 0 to 2 to find the second, third matches.
[Reference](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2699-excel-vlookup-find-first-2nd-match.html)

Comment: Construct a complete answer, link only answers can suffer link  rot and fail.

Comment: But note that OP is using `INDEX/MATCH/MATCH`, which is not the same as the formula in the linked reference, hence this solution is inaccurate.